# Angular 5 mat-expansion-panel in another one - Event-Propagation

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular-material, stoppropagation

I need to make n mat-expansion-panels in one mat-expansion-panel. 
So this is no problem so far, but when I try to open a child-panel, the close-event from the parent-panel triggers.

I also have input-fields in the header of the parent. When i click these, or press return, the closing/open-events trigger.

I tried to make a directive, to stop the click-event from bubbling, but this works only if i click on the input field. Even if i put the directive in every single html-element, it triggers/propagates the event

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
selector: '[appStopEventPropagation]'
})
export class StopEventPropagationDirective {
  constructor() { }
  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  public onClick(event:any):void{
   event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

**PARTIALLY SOLVED**

I got the return-key-problem solved, via adding a method for keydown-event in the Directive. The problem with the other expansion panels is still there.

[Nice picture with my drawings of my View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ06U.png)

The HTML is probably kinda big for no reason, but hey, it works ... a bit

[Part 1 Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb94F.png)

[Part 2 Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le2HW.png)

**SOLVED**

Comment: could you please share me your template code

Comment: I created a stackblitz demo for you, where the panels are nested and opening a child panel does not trigger the parent to close. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzjstg
May u can recreate your problem in stackblitz

Comment: @ChrisY If you post your stackblitz as an answer, i will accept your answer. forgot the arcordion around the inner panels. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the comments, the inner `mat-accordion` was missing.
Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzjstg

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue how your template look like. What you can do is:

```
<mat-panel-description>
  <input placeholder="Type your name and age" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"/>
</mat-panel-description>
```